# Projection operator onto the diagonal on Fock space.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics

I am currently working with an operator fulfilling
$$T:\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{D}^\perp.$$
That means, it is "trivially" symmetric, i.e., $\langle \psi, T \phi \rangle = 0$ for $\psi,\phi \in \mathcal{D}$.

The first question can be answered without much detail:

- Is it a fact that $\mathcal{D}^\perp$ is not dense? And does it in turn imply that $T$ is not closable?

Now to add more detail, the operator acts on the symmtrized Fock space $\mathcal{H} = \bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty P_n(L^2(\mathbb{R})^{\otimes n})$ with $P_n$ symmetrization, and increases and decreases particle number (i.e., $(T\psi_n) = (T\psi)_{n-1} + (T\psi)_{n+1}$) by acting as multiplication with a dirac delta:

$$ (T\psi)_{n-1}(x_1, .., x_{n-1}) = \psi_n(x_1, x_1, x_2, .., x_{n-1}) $$
and
$$ (T\psi)_{n+1}(x_1, .., x_{n+1}) = \delta(x_1 - x_2) \psi_n(x_1, x_3, .., x_{n+1}).$$
The domain are all $L^2$ functions with $\psi(x_1, .., x_n) =0$ if $x_i = x_j$ for $i\neq j$.

Now to my second and third question:

- Is it correct that $\mathcal{D}$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$?

And most importantly:

- Can $T$ even be defined as an operator on $\mathcal{H}$, as its Dirac delta part does not map into $\mathcal{H}$? Maybe through expectation values of $T$ which are at least well-defined finite.

I know this question is a bit fuzzy, but I tried to formulate some clear questions.

Apart from that, I would be happy to know what if $T$ could be defined as an operator (under certain assumptions) and whether something of that sort has been studied already. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Forget about Fock space. The problem is the delta function and you can already run into it in simple 1d quantum mechanics. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172993/self-adjoint-extensions-and-delta-potentials

Comment: Could you explain how it is related? I think the Fock space does make a huge difference here. I am not solving a wave equation with potential (no Laplacian) but study an operator which increases or decreases particle number. I do not see how to compare this to 1D QM with potential.

Comment: If you want to do this in a mathematically rigorous way, you have to figure out how to define an operator given by multiplication with a delta function. The Fock case is just an example of that with more bells and whistles (multivariate situation). First you need to understand how it works in 1d where the same problem is present in simpler form. A standard approach is to replace the delta by a narrow Gaussian and take the limit of the corresponding unbounded operators as the width of the Gaussian goes to zero...

Comment: ...It's nontrivial and involves a bit of renormalization (but not as hard as in QFT). The convergence is typically in the sense of strong resolvant or even norm resolvant sense. A standard math ref for this kind of things is the book "Solvable Models in Quantum Mechanics" by Albeverio et al. and they walk you through this starting in 1d and building up to the many-body case.

Comment: I see, thanks for the comment! I will look it up and update the question when I make progess.